# How can I update an alarm start up date in wp7 agent?

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm, scheduledactionservice

I would like to update alarm begin time in the ScheduledAgent, is it possible to do that in wp7 ?

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        var schedule = Find("AlarmName")

        if (schedule != null)
        {
            var alarm = schedule as Alarm;
            ReplaceAlarm(alarm);
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }

    private void ReplaceAlarm(Alarm alarm)
    {
        alarm.BeginTime = NewDateTime;
        alarm.ExpirationTime = NewExpirationTime;
        alarm.Content = "new Text";

        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Replace(alarm as ScheduledAction);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because ***ScheduledActionService.Replace*** method is not supported with BackgroundAgent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=vs.92).aspx